# How do dark stars form?

Tags: black-hole, galaxy, dark-matter

I'm not referring to a star made of dark matter or a Newtonian dark star. I'm talking about a star powered by dark matter annihilation. I imagine it would form close to the centers of galaxies where there is a large amount of dark matter.

Comment: Could you please include some reference at least (if any)?

Comment: Sure. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/716/2/1397/pdf            https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4495.pdf